# scope in Ionic2 is different?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, ionic2, ionic3

I use exercise in html like `{{exercise.name}}`.
It dosen't have problem at first.

But as you can see below, I want to have `exercise.time` value minus for every 1sec.

But I can't access exercise object in `setInterval()`. 
I logged it but only came out null.
How can I access it and give minus for every second?
(minused number should be displayed).

```
export class ExercisePage {
  exercise:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.navParams.get("data"));
    this.exercise=this.navParams.get("data");
    console.log(this.exercise);
    console.log("시간2 : "+this.exercise.time);
    var time=this.exercise.time;
    setInterval(function(){
      time--;
      console.log(this.exercise);
    },5000)
    console.log("22");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ExercisePage');
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<p>{{exercise.time}}</p>
```

I changed a bit adding reduce function but it won't work neither.

```
export class ExercisePage {
  exercise:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.navParams.get("data"));
    this.exercise=this.navParams.get("data");
    console.log(this.exercise);
    console.log("시간2 : "+this.exercise.time);
    var time=this.exercise.time;
    setInterval(function(){
      time--;
      this.reduce(time);
    },5000)
    console.log("22");
  }

  reduce(time){
    console.log("reduce : "+time);
    console.log(this.exercise.time);
    this.exercise.time=time;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use Arrow functions as sebaferreras proposed you can alternatively use this method:

```
// ...
var tthis = this; // var that = this if you prefer
setInterval(function() {
  time--;
  console.log(tthis.exercise); // It should also work! ;)
}, 5000)
// ...
```

I suggest you to use arrow functions as it is now standard (I think) in Javascript and Typescript :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). By using arrow functions, the **`this`** property is not overwritten and still references the component instance (otherwise, the `this` keyword points to the inner function, and your component's methods and variables are not defined in it):

```
// ...
setInterval(() => {
  time--;
  console.log(this.exercise); // Now it should work! :)
}, 5000)
// ...
```